# RequestParams hashmap/arralist in POST request

Tags: android, loopj

In RequestParams when doing a POST request, I want to send a hash (key/value) or an array. Is this possible using RequestParams? If so, how?

Thanks

Comment: I think the best way of achieving this is converting your hash/array into a `JSON` object. Have you tried this way?